# Switching between View Controllers (with simultaneous VCs)

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

Currently, I have a main `ViewController` that calls a `GameViewController` to load a `SKScene` in front of the main `ViewController`. I do this in the viewDidLoad of the main `ViewController` via:

```
let gameView = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Game") as! GameViewController
let top: UIViewController? = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
top?.present(gameView, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

This currently works, I have `SKScene` displayed on top of a `ViewController` that displays an image (with an `ImageView`) in the background.

However, now I want to switch to another `ViewController`, and I'm not sure how to do this. Things I have tried:

- Segues (calling them with `performSegue(withIdentifier: "mySegueID", sender: nil)` )
  NOT WORKED
- Push the new `ViewController` (with `navigationController?.pushViewController(nextViewController, animated: true)`)
  NOT WORKED
- Present the new `ViewController` (using the same code I use to display the `GameViewController`)

THIS 'PRESENT VIEWCONTROLLLER' WORKED. However, after I called the next `ViewController` then dismissed it via a segue triggered by a button push in the new `ViewController`, the new `ViewController` wouldn't call again with the 'present `ViewController`' method anymore.

Any ideas on how to successfully switch between `ViewController`s (with one of them having a `GameViewController` simultaneously)?

Comment: the better way to keep these navigation stack. (push and pop). but you presenting them then don't use segue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wonder how segues didn't work for u? 
You need to give segue an identifier and then call it in some function or action(like buttonPressed) or somth. 
in performSegue(withIdentifier: "urSegueIdentifier", sender: Any?.self)
i'm not sure if sender can be nil, maybe try .self?

Comment: Thanks so much!! I released that my segue wasn't working because I was calling it while dismissing a `UIImagePicker`. If I added a delay to the segue, it worked consistently! Thanks again :)